# jira: color highlight changes in history

Tags: jira, highlight, history, jira-plugin

we are using Jira to write our User Storys. These can be "very" big. If someone does a change you get an new entry in the history tap. But since their you can just see the old and the new version is is veeeeery hard to see in one sentence has been changed in a long text.
Does anybody know a plugin or something how it is easier to see what has changed? For example that the location of the actual change is highlighted in red or green.

Comment: Jira notification emails have nicely formatted diffs that make it clear what changed in text. The web app history diffs are nearly useless for any text blocks greater than a few words in length.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any add-on that provides this functionality, but there is a feature request for JIRA that you can vote on: [JRA-20112](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-20112).

Comment: thanks for the answer. We will see if they implement this feature in 3 or 6 years :(

Comment: Another option is to implement it yourself as a custom JIRA add-on :)